# Possible to query all SQL Server Indexes which have page locks enabled?

Tags: sql-server-2005, index

Is it possible to run a SQL Server Query in order to view all SQL Server Indexes which have page locks enabled?

Comment: Be warned that the normal state of an index is to **have** page locks enabled. Mess with this setting at your own peril.

Comment: We had two specific Non-Clustered Indexes with the setting "use page locks when accessing the index", which caused (according to trace 1222) a deadlock. I removed the 2 page locks today, am I at risk for removing them? The problem was that they were deadlocking on unrelated data. Thanks SQL Kiwi - this is important to know what you said because we have index rebuilding happening - if i have it set as to Reorganize then it will cause an error - I need to know of this.

Comment: @PeterPitLock - RE: The deadlocks please supply the requested information to your other question (full table definition and full deadlock trace output)

Comment: @MartinSmith, gonna try and export an example version of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS object_schema,
       OBJECT_NAME(object_id)        AS object_name,
       name                          AS index_name
FROM   sys.indexes
WHERE  allow_page_locks = 1
```